# How to dynamically insert Angular 2 components into html created by third party libraries?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-components

I know that we can create dynamic components using component factory resolver. But as far as I know that only allows us to insert dynamic angular 2 components into other angular 2 components. I have a third party library that I am using to create DOM during the afterViewInit lifecycle hook. And I would like to insert an angular 2 component into the DOM that the library creates.

I would like to know how I can do that?

Comment: do you want to insert a DOM generated by the 3rd party library into a component view?

Comment: Maximus, no, I want to do the opposite, insert angular 2 component, into DOM created by third party library.

Comment: what do you mean by angular component? DOM nodes in component view? you will not have synchronization between data model and DOM without angular framework